# Cypress.js : How to change default path for your e2e tests?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, cypress, e2e

in v13.3.0, after you install Cypress.js into your repo, it creates these four default directories:

- **/cypress/e2e**
- /cypress/fixtures
- /cypress/support
- /cypress/downloads

the first one is where it expects your e2e tests to go and it watches its contents on-fly.

but what if i want to have my e2e tests stored elsewhere?

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#e2e

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in the root of your repo Cypress will place **cypress.config.js**

**default** content of it is:

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});
```

i have my e2e tests in:
**tests/cypress/**

so i added the **specPattern** line, which made it working for me (after i saved the file):

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    specPattern: 'tests/cypress/**/*.cy.js',
  },
});
```

any file(s) with extensions *.cy.js* in the directory *tests/cypress/* or in further sub-directories, will match.

official documentation:

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#e2e

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/component-framework-configuration#Spec-Pattern-for-Component-Tests

Answer (score -1):

In Cypress.js, you can change the default path for your end-to-end (E2E) tests by specifying the integrationFolder option in your configuration file (cypress.json or cypress.env.json). By default, Cypress looks for test files inside the cypress/integration directory. If you want to change this path, follow these steps:

Create a configuration file (if you don't have one):

If you don't have a cypress.json file in your project, you can create one in your project's root directory.

Specify the custom integration folder path:

Inside your cypress.json file, add the integrationFolder option with the desired path to your E2E test files. For example:
{
"integrationFolder": "path/to/your/tests"
}

Replace "path/to/your/tests" with the actual path to the directory where your E2E test files are located.

Run Cypress with the custom configuration:

Once you've set the custom integration folder path in your cypress.json file, Cypress will look for test files in the specified directory when you run your tests.

You can run Cypress using the following command in your terminal or command prompt:
npx cypress open
or
npx cypress run
Cypress will now use the custom path you specified for your E2E tests.

Remember to adjust the path in the integrationfolder option based on your project's directory structure. This allows you to organize your tests in a way that makes sense for your project.